# Slicing using pointer to a slice

Tags: go

I am trying to modify slice a slice in another function, using the following code:

```
type DT struct {
    name string
    number int
}

func slicer(a *[]DT) {
    tmp := *a
    var b []DT
    b = append(b, tmp[:1], tmp[2:])
    *a = b
}

func main() {
    o1 := DT {
        name: "name-1",
        number: 1,
    }
    o2 := DT {
        name: "name-2",
        number: 2,
    }
    o3 := DT {
        name: "name-3",
        number: 3,
    }

    b := make([]DT, 0)
    b = append(b, o1)
    b = append(b, o2)
    b = append(b, o3)

    slicer(&b)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

What I want is, 1st and last element of the slice. But, in doing so, I am getting following error:

```
cannot use tmp[:1] (type []DT) as type DT in append
```

I am relatively new to Go Language, so kindly guide me through this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use operator `...` to convert slice into list of variadic arguments.

```
 b = append(b, tmp[:1]...)
 b = append(b, tmp[2:]...)
```

Comment: can you please explain, what it does. It actually fixed!